# will type conversion take place in given code?

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
void main()
{
printf("%f",12/7.0);
getch();
}
```

Will the type conversion take place in this code and if yes then why it is taking place and if no why it is not taking place in this code please explain? Also I think 7.0 which is of double data type here (according to rule of type conversion) and 12 which is of integer data type would give data type double but when I print with %lf then the output on screen is again float I don't know how please correct me ?

Comment: See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). Specifically "the usual arithmetic conversions". You need to understand that the constants `12` and `7.0` have types just like variables.

Comment: For printf arguments there is this https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions and if you are wondering what type 7.0 is, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant

Comment: To add to @Lundin useful comment, you can qualify constants with literals : `printf("%f",12.0f/7.0f);` for example qualify the constants as `float` (literal suffix f).

Comment: What makes you think that the output is `float`? What do you expect to see if it is `double`?

Comment: @the busybee because I have used format specifier %f therefore I think the output should convert from double (12/7.0) (because I have learnt 7.0 would as a constant would be stored as double in the memory) to float and if I use double (because I think that the expression (12/7.0) would be double according to type conversion and that should be stored in double format specifier %lf) and give output upto 15 decimal places but it is giving output only upto 6 decimal places tell me where i am wrong and if it has to do something with different rule please explain that rule also?

Comment: I was afraid that you mis-interpreted things, and I seem to be right. So please read Jean-Baptiste's answer, and I'm sure you will mark it. ;-) However, a closer look in any good C book could have revealed this to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deduce the type of the expression by the result of the printing. `printf` may show you only part of the value...

man `printf` says for `f` or `F` format (emphasize is mine):

> fF
>
> The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in the style `[-]ddd.ddd`, where
> the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.
> **If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;** if the precision is explicitly zero, no decimal-
> point character appears.  If a decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it.

12 is an `int` literal, `7.0` is a `double` literal. By the rules of expression evaluation `int` will be promoted to `double` and the result will be a `double` that is printed according to the format (`f` is not for `float` but for `double`).

If you want to print the value computed by a `float` division, you need to restrict to `float` using:

```
12/7.0f
```

The result will be `float`, and you may ask *why do I use a `double` specifier then?* Because, in any variadic function every `float` will be promoted to `double`. As `printf`  is a variadic function...
This is why there is no `float` specifier in format string of `printf`.